# How to resolve the No + [RCTConvert AIR MapCoordinate Array] error: function found. react native maps on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, react-native-maps

I used react-native maps react-native-maps ":" ^ 0.24.2 and react native version 0.59.9 I experienced error maps on iOS but there was no error on Android.

I have tried removing pod, link and unlink library following the documentation

`no +[rctconvert airmapcoordinatearray:] function found.`

I hope that react-native-maps runs on iOS and Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to relink with native ios files. Basically do [manual installation of ios again](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md#option-3-manually)

**OR**

```
react-native unlink react-native-maps

react-native link react-native-maps
```

Then remove any duplicated imports (if any)

Comment: What you mean about duplicate import.

Comment: This is because if the same module is reconnected, it can be added twice more.

Comment: Can you give an examples?.

Comment: For example, if you need to import, if you are to link twice, the same phrase may be written twice.